# Disable markers if data > 1 in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to make markers disabled while data > 1 after insert new data? It's really confusing me..

In this case, I want to make a Grow Chart (chart example source: CDC-Weight for age percentiles)

Should I use this?

```
if(dataChartWeight.length > 1)
{
   chart.series[19].update({
     marker: {
       enabled: false
     }
   }, true);
}
if(dataChartLength.length > 1)
{
   chart.series[18].update({
     marker: {
       enabled: false
     }
   }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20214241/5172918) is good but it can become a little more complicated to fix if you are using multiple series, using a custom tooltip, or when the chart is redrawn. In stead of using destroy(); on the graphic, I used hide();

I wrapped it up in a function and then called the function on first load, and also on the redraw event. It loops through each series first, then loops through the data to "hide" the markers with zero as value.

```
$(function () {

    function hideZeroDots(chart) {
        $.each(chart.series, function (series) {
            $.each(chart.series[series].data, function () {
                if(this.y === 0 && this.graphic) {
                    this.graphic.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({        
        title: {
            text: 'Hide Zero Dots'
        },
        chart: {
            events: {
                redraw: function () {
                    hideZeroDots(this);
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                hideDelay: 0,
                shared: true,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                borderColor: '#eee',
                shadow: false,
                crosshairs: {
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'gray',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdot'
                }
        }, 
        series: [{
                name: 'responses',          
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36.5, 33.3, 0, 23.9, 0]
            }, {
                name: 'views',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26.5, 23.3, 0, 13.9, 0]
            }]
        }, hideZeroDots);
});
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krksgthy/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally marker cannot be disabled for single point, but you can use workaround with hiding SVG element.

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data, function (point, i) {
            if(this.y <10) {
                this.graphic.destroy();
            }
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5HzV/2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to disable the marker, you can hide it...

```
marker: {
   radius:0,
   lineWidth:0,
}
```